# Check for empty string in JSX

Tags: string, redux, reactjs

Is there a way in React/JSX to check if a user's input string is empty?

Component.js

```
{((this.props.description.name ==" ")||(this.props.description.name.length==""))?
```

This condition works when a user inputs nothing or an empty string that is 1 space long, but if the empty string is more than 1 space long it fails. Is there a trick with JSX to check this or should I handle this in my reducer?

Comment: Trim the string and check if the length is 0.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could check for trimmed string:

```
{this.props.description.name.trim() == ""}
```

This trims the string (which removes whitespace and newlines) and then check is if it's an empty string. Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkgbRW) demonstration.

Comment: Why would you check both? If `name == ""` then the length is 0.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli completely forgot the `trim()`, edited

Comment: `this.props.description.trim().name` ?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Slipped through again! Thanks :)

Comment: Which comes back to the original point, why would you check them both? If `name.trim() == ""` then length must be 0.

Comment: What is description is null? Won't calling .trim() on a null value cause an error?

Comment: @Dan That's isn't covered in the question. They you'd just check it with a null check (or truthy check)

Answer (score 6):

You can easily to trim the text and compare with empty string.
Let try:

```
{((this.props.description.name.trim() =="") || (this.props.description.name.trim().length==0))
```

to see how it's work.
I've seen you remind about Reducer? You are using Redux, aren't?
If you use Redux, for handling form data, you could use Redux Form (https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) to save your time.

Comment: When is the length property equal to a string?

Comment: Why would `trim()` ever equal `" "`?

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer.

Comment: Nested block is redundant.